# Object Lock in Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

i am trying to learn Multithreading in java and stuck over the below code.(Concept of Object lock)

```
public class MultiThreading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //creating threads.
        MyThread1 t1=new MyThread1();  
        MyThread2 t2=new MyThread2();  

        //start threads.
        t1.start();  
        t2.start();  

    }

}

class MyThread1 extends Thread{    
    public void run(){ 
        //PrintTable.printTable(2);  
        PrintTable p = new PrintTable();
        p.printTable1(2);
    }        
}  

class MyThread2 extends Thread{   
    public void run(){  
        //PrintTable.printTable(5);  
        PrintTable p = new PrintTable();
        p.printTable1(5);
    }  
}
```

**Printable.java**

public class PrintTable {

```
    public void printTable1(int n){

           synchronized(this)
           {
               System.out.println("Started "+n);

               try{  
                     Thread.sleep(1000);  
                   }catch(Exception e){
                     System.out.println(e);
                   }  
                   System.out.println("Ended "+n);
           }


        }
```

In the above code , according to my understanding if **Thread1** is accessing method **printTable1** , then no other **Thread2** will get       access to same **printTable1** method until Thread1 completes execution,       because Thread1 will acquire lock on Printable object .

But the output that i got is

```
Started 2
Started 5
Ended 2
Ended 5
```

It should have been

```
Started 2
Ended 2
Started 5
Ended 5
```

Am i wrong in my concept ?? If yes then please correct me .

Comment: You are wrong. You are synchronizing on two different objects. They do not affect each other.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your threads creates a **new** instance of `PrintTable`.
And the code in `PrintTable` is `synchronized` on `this`.

This means that the two instances are synchronized on two different locks.

Answer (score 0):

> synchronized(this)

means you are synchronizing on the current object instance.

problem is that both threads create new instances of PrintTable.

You may use the following (Class level locking) in place of synchronized(this)

```
  private final static Object lock=new Object();

  synchronized (lock) {

 }
```